# Identify values in column that occur more than once

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Loop through records in CSV and identify values in the first column (i.e., row[0]) which occur at least 4x in dataset (CSV) and print those rows (records).

Example of data:

```
address                     salesprice
1 RIVER TERRACE             6000000
10 LITTLE WEST STREET       2500000
15 WILLIAM STREET           1140000
15 WILLIAM STREET           885878
15 WILLIAM STREET           997885
15 WILLIAM STREET           1220881.75
120 GREENWICH STREET        625000
```

Sample code (which failed)

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('path/myfile.csv', 'r',newline='') as f:
    myfile = csv.reader(f)
    for row in myfile:
        #print(row[0])
        if Counter.items(row[0]) > 4:
            print(row)
```

Comment: csv file without commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myfile.csv

```
address,salesprice
1,RIVER TERRACE,6000000
10,LITTLE WEST STREET,2500000
15,WILLIAM STREET,1140000
15,WILLIAM STREET,885878
15,WILLIAM STREET,997885
15,WILLIAM STREET,1220881.75
120,GREENWICH STREET,625000
```

code

```
import collections, csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    rows = [x for x in csv.reader(f)]
    count = collections.Counter([x[0] for i, x in enumerate(rows) if i > 0])
    for row in rows:
        if count.get(row[0], 0) > 3:
            print(row)
```

Comment: went to the trouble of including a comma delimited test file. I think he understood the problems with the non-default delimiter in the OP. One could solve it with the delimiter parameter or by defining a new dialect `csv.register_dialect('my_dialect', delimiter='\t')
with open('path/myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    myfile = csv.reader(f, 'my_dialect')` or whatever he has. Not clear to me what his original delimiter is, although it is clear he didn't represent it as ",".

Comment: yes but the `csv.reader()` defaults to `,` as a delimiter so I am assuming it is comma delimited due to him not specifying it

Answer (score 1):

You need to count first doing one full pass over the reader object and then  read the file again:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

with open('path/myfile.csv', 'r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # get counts first
    cn = Counter(map(itemgetter(0),r))
    # reset pointer to beginning of file
    f.seek(0)
    # create another reader
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # now iterate over the rows again, checking count of each row[0]
    for row in r:
        if cn[row[0]] > 4:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to read all the lines in the file.  You build your counter on that set.

Second, you iterate through the keys of your counter and check the values for being >= 4.  (Note that you only did > ... you have to include 4).

Is that enough to let you write your own code?

Comment: Not that I disagree with your answer, but this is more of a comment.

Answer (score -1):

just in python....

```
from collections import Counter
import  re

with open('data') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()

# this will get as num - most common number, and cnt as count for it
num, cnt = Counter( [e.split(',',1)[0] for e in lines] ).most_common(1)[0]

if int(cnt) >= 4:
   for line in lines:
       if re.match(num,line):
           print(line)

15,WILLIAM STREET,1140000

15,WILLIAM STREET,885878

15,WILLIAM STREET,997885

15,WILLIAM STREET,1220881.75
```